# Show that there exists ﬁelds properly containing $\mathbb{C}$. Does that ﬁeld have the property that every non-constant polynomial over it has a root?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question comes after showing that if $\mathrm R$ is a domain, then $\mathrm R[t]$ is also a domain. But I don't quite see the connections here. Since polynomials of complex coefficients isn't a field since there aren't inverses to every element.

Comment: The [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) over $\Bbb C$ form a field properly containing $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb{C}(x)$, where $\Bbb{C}(x)$ is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $\Bbb{C}[x]$. Clearly  $\Bbb{C}\subset \Bbb{C} (x) $.

> A field $F$ is algebraically closed if any polynomial of non-zero
>   degree over $F$ has at least one root in $F.$

$\Bbb{C}(x)$ is not algebraically closed. To see this, let $F=\Bbb{C}(x)$ and $F[y]$ be the polynomial ring over $F$.

Consider $$f(y)=y^2-\frac1x\in F[y].$$ If there exists a root in $F$, it must be of the form $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$,$p (x),q(x)\in \Bbb{C}[x]$. Then   $${\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)}^2=\frac1x\iff x{p(x)}^2={q(x)}^2.$$
Can you see the contradiction?

Hence $\Bbb{C}(x)$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: I think I get the first part now. But I think the question asks for whether polynomials over this field has root, not in this field. Do you mean $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is also algebraically closed?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Is the contradiction that $q(x)$ must be $\sqrt{x}p(x)$. and $\sqrt{x}$ is not in $\mathbb{C}(x)$

Comment: Yes. Also note that degree of $x {p (x)}^2$ is odd whereas degree of  ${q (x)}^2$ is even.